# RHF & React-Query Multiple APIs for one form

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, react-hook-form, react-query

Example code: https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/elated-silence-mbk9s5

I'll try to keep this brief, but I'm looking for some clarification!

I'm trying out some stuff using React-Hook-Form and React-Query. So I have a React TS app, an ASP.NET Core Web API and a database.

In the database, for example, I have two tables: dbo.User & dbo.Quote. dbo.User typically has records that look like this:

```
id: 1
name: "john doe"
username: "johndoe"
email: "johndoe@example.com"
phone: 0000000000
website: "johndoe.com"
quote: 1
```

And dbo.Quote typically has records like this:

```
id: 1
quote: "This is a quote"
id: 2
quote: "This is a another quote"
id: 3
quote: "This is yet another quote"
```

So, of course, dbo.User's 'quote' column is a FK reference to dbo.Quote's 'id' column. With all that foundation aside, and just to emphasise that I have control over the api and db layers here:

In my react application, I make an API call to '/api/user' to fetch the user's information. Great! That populates pretty much everything on the forum. But I need a select/dropdown of quotes for the user to choose from. So, I'm guessing that means I have to make a second API call to '/api/quote' to get all the records from the db and map them as dropdown options.

I'm just wondering if that is the right approach, as it seems a bit ugly to me, but I am newish to react, so still learning. I've produced a minimal example here using fake rest APIs to better illustrate what I am asking:

https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/elated-silence-mbk9s5

You'll see that I have two custom hooks being used in App.tsx lines 8 & 9.

The information retrieved from '/api/quote' will very rarely change. Maybe -- maybe once a week, or once every 2 weeks. So, maybe I would be better to fetch all of my reference data from the api when the react application is first loaded? I'm not sure.

Hopefully somebody can give me a best practises or architecture lesson here! Thanks.